# Issues while deploying java EE app

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, jdbc, glassfish

I am deploying a java EE application. Encountered some error while building and deploying it. Trying to interpret it but have no clues. I'm using JDBC and glassfish 4.01 for this experimental purpose.

```
SEVERE:   Servlet [RegistrationRequesterPortTypePortImpl] and Servlet [RegistrationCoordinatorPortTypePortImpl] have the same url pattern: [/RegistrationService_V10]
SEVERE:   Exception while deploying the app [bank]
SEVERE:   Exception during lifecycle processing
```

And the following error:

```
WARNING:   The web application [unknown] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
WARNING:   The web application [unknown] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
SEVERE:   Exception while deploying the app [bank] : Servlet [RegistrationRequesterPortTypePortImpl] and Servlet [RegistrationCoordinatorPortTypePortImpl] have the same url pattern: [/RegistrationService_V10]. Related annotation information: annotation [@javax.jws.WebService(wsdlLocation=/wsdls/wsc10/wscoor.wsdl, targetNamespace=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/10/wscoor, name=, endpointInterface=com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v10.types.RegistrationCoordinatorPortType, portName=RegistrationCoordinatorPortTypePort, serviceName=RegistrationService_V10)] on annotated element [class com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v10.endpoint.RegistrationCoordinatorPortTypePortImpl] of type [TYPE]
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/account.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Please add your `web.xml` to the question.

Comment: @unwichtich just added web.xml.

Comment: The web.xml looks normal...do you have any clue which part of your code introduced the problem?

Comment: Ever get the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue, and was able to fix it by changing one of my Maven dependencies. glassfish-embedded-all.jar was causing the problem, once it was removed my application started up normally. Unfortunately I can't tell you with witch other lib it was clashing, but with some digging you might find it.

Hope this helps.

I changed

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure any JSF @ConversationalScoped or @ViewScoped controllers implement java.io.Serializable.